# Git cherry-pick creates blobs not commits?

Tags: git, tags, diff

There was a regression in a feature added a few months back. The feature was introduced in three separate commits. In order to restore the functionality I wanted to `git cherry-pick` the three commits onto a branch (rel060) created from the last tag (release-0.6.0) made before the commits were merged in to production, indicated by `git describe`.

This completed, I want to compare the results of this operation to the contents of a file on current production head.

```
git co -b rel060 release-0.6.0
git cherry-pick ead47f2
  [rel060 f28fed4] Corrects non-display of subtabs. (SITE-657)
  1 files changed, 5 insertions(+), 8 deletions(-)
git cherry-pick b22c4d4
  [rel060 b0014f1] Correct subtab bug in Firefox/IE. (SITE-657)
  1 files changed, 18 insertions(+), 24 deletions(-)
git cherry-pick ae5a321
  [rel060 5b41410] Corrects bug with subtab line collapse. (SITE-657)
  1 files changed, 5 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)
git diff rel060:./cron_lp_functions.php..production:./cron_db_lpgenerate.php
  error: Object 2ce3dd45e32e1bef6da0b22a9ee7208c63e203d2 is a blob, not a commit
  error: Object f41574b41b82aba51876b5f7aba0d3ff9c6677c5 is a blob, not a commit
  fatal: Invalid revision range rel060:./cron_lp_functions.php..production:./cron_db_lpgenerate.php
```

For what it's worth, attempting to tab autocomplete at cron_lp_... produced: `Not a valid object name rel060:.`

The `functions` file is a file whose contents were later rolled in to the `lpgenerate`.

Now, I realize there are a million easier alternatives to do what I want to do (see the three commits as one diff, diff the tag releasing the feature to the current state of the lines in question).

What I want to know is this: why did I get the particular errors? As it turns out, cherry-picking seems to have nothing to o with the problem. Attempting the diff after creating the branch from the tag produces the same error. Have I missed something fundamental in git? Creating a branch from a release seems innocuous... are there some innocuous gotchas I'm not picking up on?

Comment: What does `git rev-parse release-0.6.0` say (and also for `rel060` and `production`)? What is `git co` (I'm guessing it's an alias for `git checkout`, but it's worth checking)? It almost looks like you've somehow created tags/branches pointing to blobs instead of commits, but that would certainly be unusual...

Comment: ```git rev-parse release-0.6.0     533ccfa0660697c6e60fde24f1d4a631d35055cc```
```git rev-parse production 5baacdbafb5e5fefa7d915f384e81f9152b7dcef```
```git rev-parse rel060 34dbae8565c445834ab4bca7cbad490828f26077```

Yes, alias for ```git checkout```

All resolve to actual commits when I ```git show```

Comment: Try `git diff rel060:./cron_lp_functions.php production:./cron_db_lpgenerate.php` (without the `..` between the two objects).

Comment: That's it! Thanks for the help. Didn't realize the syntax for interbranch file comparisons was different than between two commits.

Comment: Yep, I just ran a test myself, and `git diff` seems ok with `git diff <commit>..<commit>`, but not with `git diff <commit>:<path>..<commit>:<path>`. For that case it seems the two specifications need to be separate arguments. Might be worth reporting that as a bug/deficiency.

Comment: Just submitted to mailing list as inconsistency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is `git diff <commit>..<commit>` exists only to maintain backward compatibility and is syntactically 'wrong'.

> git diff A..B" is an illogical thing to say in the first place.  It
>   only happens to work by historical accident, and for that "it used
>   to work like so from the beginning, do not break backward
>   compatibility" reason, we have kept it working.
>
> But you are better off unlearning it to keep your sanity when
>   learning git as a new user.
>
> The dot notation is about a range.  A..B talks about the set of
>   commits that are ancestors of B but not ancestors of A.
>
> ```
> $ git log A..B
> ```
>
> makes perfect sense to show such a range.
>
> But "diff" is about "comparing two endpoints".  There is nothing
>   "range" about such a comparison.  When you compare the state at A
>   and at B, you do not even look at anything in between.  That is why
>   the canonical way to say it is
>
> ```
> $ git diff A B
> ```
>
> and not
>
> ```
> $ git diff A..B ;# WRONG. DO NOT DO THIS.
> ```
>
> And : is a way to name an entity at  in the tree
>   recorded in the .  Typically you name a blob, not a tree
>   that represents a subdirectory, with this syntax.
>
> Now, B1..B2, when B1 and B2 are blobs (or anything that is not
>   commit-ish), does not make sense even as a range, and such a request
>   is detected as an error at the syntactic level (i.e. without even
>   starting to "compare").
>
> ```
> $ git diff HEAD:Makefile..HEAD~4:Makefile ;# WRONG. DO NOT DO THIS.
> ```
>
> If you want to compare two blobs, you can do so with the canonical
>   "compare two things" syntax.
>
> ```
> $ git diff HEAD:Makefile HEAD~4:Makefile
> ```

Answer from Junio C. Hamano, via git@vger.kernel.org